# How to rename file in subdirectories using subdirectory name

Tags: bash

I hope this is not a duplicate, because it may be very basic in bash, but I always find similar questions, but with different outcomes.
I have many subdirectories, each of it containing a "`aaa.txt`" file, which is the only txt file in the subdirectory. The txt filename is always the same (so in the example above, is always "aaa", in each subdirectory).
I need to add the subdirectory name to the txt files. So assuming I have `./AAA/aaa.txt` and `./BBB/aaa.txt`, the results of the script should be:
`./AAA/AAA_aaa.txt` and `./BBB/BBB_aaa.txt`

Answer (score 2):

You can use dirname command to get the directory name and the basename command to get the file name, then construct your desired destination name. Assuming you are using only one directory level, you can set, for example

```
FILEPATH=AAA/aaa.txt
```

and do the rename with

```
mv "$FILEPATH" "$(dirname "$FILEPATH")/$(dirname "$FILEPATH")_$(basename "$FILEPATH")"
```

Comment: thank you for your reply. Maybe I am missing something, but your solution didn't work for me. I had this error: 
mv: target 'AAA_aaa.txt' is not a directory
Do you know why this is happening?

Comment: Not sure. Could you put an echo in front of the command to see what bash thinks you are trying to do...    echo mv $FILEPATH $(dirname $FILEPATH)/$(dirname $FILEPATH)_$(basename $FILEPATH)

Comment: Sure, this is what I get:
mv AAA/aaa.txt BBB/aaa.txt AAA BBB/AAA BBB_aaa.txt.
By the way, I find a solution for my problem here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14306117/rename-files-in-multiple-directories-to-the-name-of-the-directory

Comment: Good to hear you found a solution.